# No package php7.0-zip available

Tags: php, apache, zip

I'm running php7 on a redhat machine and am getting the following error in laravel:

```
Class 'ZipArchive' not found
```

I had this issue on my personal virtual machine server and all I had to do was run:

```
sudo yum install php7.0-zip
```

On my dev server I tried running the command and I get:

```
sudo yum install php7.0-zip
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
No package php7.0-zip available.
```

Just for more information here is my php version:

```
php -v
PHP 7.1.12 (cli) (built: Dec  1 2017 13:53:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Edit: If I run php7.1-zip

```
sudo yum install php7.1-zip
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
epel/x86_64/metalink                                     |  16 kB     00:00     
gitlab_gitlab-ee/x86_64/signature                        |  836 B     00:00     
gitlab_gitlab-ee/x86_64/signature                        | 1.0 kB     00:00 !!! 
gitlab_gitlab-ee-source/signature                        |  836 B     00:00     
gitlab_gitlab-ee-source/signature                        |  951 B     00:00 !!! 
icinga-stable-release                                    | 2.5 kB     00:00     
jenkins                                                  | 2.9 kB     00:00     
plesk-php-5.6                                            | 2.9 kB     00:00     
plesk-php-7.0                                            | 2.9 kB     00:00     
remi-php71                                               | 2.9 kB     00:00     
remi-safe                                                | 2.9 kB     00:00     
(1/2): remi-php71/primary_db                               | 208 kB   00:00     
(2/2): remi-safe/primary_db                                | 1.1 MB   00:01     
No package php7.1-zip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: The output to `php -v` shows that you're running PHP 7.1, so installing `php7.0-zip` doesn't sound right.

Comment: I'll edit my comment to show what happens when I run php7.1-zip

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem. I was getting:

> No package php7.0-zip available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

when running

```
yum install php7.0-zip
```

I first searched all yum packages by running:

```
yum search php70-zip
```

if returns nothing then run :

```
yum search php70-php-zip
```

if returned:

> php70-zip.x86_64 : ZIP archive management extension for PHP

Then I installed the package that the search told me was there:

```
yum install php70-zip.x86_64
```

The installation worked like a charm. Then I restarted my apache server.

```
service httpd restart
```

Now php zip (for php7) is installed!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem for PHP 7.1. I learned about `yum search` on the zip package:

```
$ yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 search php71 | grep zip
php71-php-pecl-zip.x86_64 : A ZIP archive management extension
```

I installed it:

```
$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php71-php-pecl-zip
```

For some reason, the files `zip.so` and `zip.ini` were missing in `/usr/lib64/php/modules` and `/etc/php.d/` directories respectively. So I copied them:

```
$ sudo cp /opt/remi/php71/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so /usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so
$ sudo cp /etc/opt/remi/php71/php.d/40-zip.ini /etc/php.d/40-zip.ini
```

Finally, I restarted the services

```
$ sudo systemctl restart  php-fpm nginx
```

And I can see that `zip` is loaded:

```
$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
bz2
calendar
...
zip
zlib
```

Comment: See my answer above, proper way is to install php-pecl-zip NOT php71-php-pecl-zip

Comment: @remi Thanks, I actually read your answer, I thought I was following your way. So it seems I actually don't quite understand what you wrote; I am quite a noob. But the steps I described resolved the issue for me, I'm now moved on. If I need to do another setup, I will see if  `$ sudo yum --enablerepo=remi-php71 install php-pecl-zip` would work better, ie, without copying files. I appreciate your time in helping noob like me, who prefers to spend time developing app rather than setting up servers.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using some plesk package, this is not really a RHEL/CentOS server.

What is the package name providing the php command ?

```
rpm -qf $(which php)
```

- If **php-cli**-7.1.12 (from remi-php71), you need **php-pecl-zip** from the
  same repository
- If **php71-php-cli**-7.1.12 (from remi-safe, SCL package) you
  need **php71-php-pecl-zip** from the same repository

General rule, for any *foo* extension yum install *package_namespace-foo* should work, as explained by the [Wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).

Answer (score 3):

I know is an old thread, but I faced same problem on CENTOS, and I solved similar (but quite different way):

```
yum search php70-zip
```

No Matches found

```
yum search php70-php-zip
```

found this

```
ea-php70-php-zip.x86_64 : A module for PHP applications that need to handle .z
                    : files
```

then

```
sudo yum install ea-php70-php-zip.x86_64
```

and it was successfully installed

after that I restarted apache

```
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

and problem was solved

I took me a lot of time, because I did not know package name, difficult for me, I found that on web: ea-php70-php-zip.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try to install php7.1-zip or php-zip packages...

Comment: 7.1 yields the same result. php-zip works installs but doesn't fix my issue. php-zip is for pre-php7 right?

Comment: php-zip works fine for me with php7.0 on Ubuntu 16.04. (For older php versions, I think you have to recompile php with option --enable-zip)
Have you restarted your webserver (apache/nginx/other) after the package install ? (just in case of...)
Else, you can also see if the extension is installed and enabled with the cli command "php -i | grep zip"